# settimeout works fine in ios 5 but does not work in ios 6

Tags: ios6, settimeout

I have a simple html code with JS that should sign in to a regulation unit in background and after timeout it loads online schema. It was working well, but now some of my customers upgraded to ios6 and this code does not work any more. Could anyone help?

The code is below

```
<html>
<head>
<body onload="document.BLD1.submit(); setTimeout('document.load.submit()',5000);">

<form method="post" name="BLD1" action="http://77.48.234.213:8080/main.html" target="loginWindow1">
<input name="blu" type="hidden" value="5" /><input name="blp" type="hidden" size="10" maxlength="8" value="0000" /><input name="bll" type="hidden" value="logovani " /> </form>


<form style="font: 12pt;" action="http://77.48.234.213:8080/GRAFIK.htm" name="load" target="targetWINDOW">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```